how to get lines from message in discord.py
i try to create bot that can read crypto deals
i want to get each line but i get only letter
for example:
i send this command in discord :
symbol:btc
price:65,000
stop loss: xyz
and i want to get each line and i get only letter from the first word
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if (message.author.id == 825852515122937866 and message.channel.id == 1105902259033870400): 
    if 'ns' in message.content:
        print(message.content[0])
    else:
        print('dontwork')
  else:
    print('cant find any message')

i tried to do message.content[0]
but its give me only the first letter of the first word

After I divided the message into parts, how do I break the line into 2 parts? –

What is the message.content? Can you provide an example?

You have to split the message string, in your case by space (if I understood correctly). So something like this:
lines = message.split(' ')
for line in lines:
    ...


After I divided the message into parts, how do I break the line into 2 parts?

You have to split line again by :, I assume

lines = message.content.split('\n')
message = (lines[1:0])
its give me nothing
